# Python Pandas Data Frame Count values of one column based on another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to count the values of one column based on the values of another.  Say for example you have 3 columns, User ID, Status, and Status_counts.  User ID is a unique identifier for each person, Status either says complete or not complete, then status counts gives the number of times complete or not complete appears for that specific user id.  Example table below:

```
User ID| Status            Status counts
1     | Complete.     |   12
1     | Not complete. |   11
```

I want to add two columns to this.  In one column, I want the number of times complete appears (12 in my example above) divided by the sum of complete and not complete for that specific user.  So this column would look at the user id (here it would be like if user id = 1), add up its status counts (12 + 11 here), then create a column that takes the status counts for just complete (12 here) and divide sum of status counts (12 +11 ), so it would be (12/ 11 + 12). I then want to do this for not complete (11 / 12 +11). I want to do this for many different user ids.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is not a well defined function: what would the output be for the row of `Not Complete` in your Complete Rate Column? There are ways I can think of doing this, but it will be aggregated on an index different from the index you currently have (we would have to group by User ID and the Status and Status Counts columns would disappear)

Comment: the output would be 11 (the value of status_counts not complete) divided by the total sum of status count for this specific user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'UserID':[1,1],'Status':['complete','not complete'],'Count':[12,11]})

def helper(data):
    num= data[data['Status']=='complete']['Count']
    denum = int(data[data['Status']=='not complete']['Count']) + int(data[data['Status']=='complete']['Count'] )
    return  num / denum

df.groupby('UserID').apply(helper)
```

This will produce the following output:

```
Count   0
UserID
1     .521739
```

Comment: how did you deal with getting NaN as your output?

Comment: I noticed that when I didn't wrap the two parts of the denominator in an `int()` wrapper, It returned `NaN`. Not entirely sure why this happened, but as soon as I used `int()` the problem was solved.